# How to display custom error message instead of the exception in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have connected my Flutter application to MySQL. In my PHP file I have written a query to retrieve data from MySQL. If the query executes successfully the data is returning and am able to display it in my listtile.

However if the query fails (if the required column is not available in my table) I want to display "no data found" only. But am getting "Error format exception".  How to hide this error format exception?

```
_getUsers() async {
       var data = await http
        .post("http://10.0.2.2/Flutter/count.php", body: {
        "dat": count,
    
    });
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);
    return jsonData;
  }
```

and my build is

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.teal,
          
          child: new FutureBuilder(
              future: _getUsers(), 
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Center(
                    child: new Text('Error ${snapshot.error}'),
                  );
                }
               
                else {
                    return Center(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(56.0, 8.0, 56.0, 8.0),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                           return ListTile(
                              leading: new Text(
                                '${snapshot.data[index]["branch"]}',
                                 style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 25.0,
                                  ),
                              ),
                              trailing: new Text(
                                '${snapshot.data[index]["count(`branch`)".toString()]}',
                                 style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 25.0,
                                 
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                           
                          }),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using the below solution make sure you are getting a List of map/json as response. i.e. structure must be similar to:

```
[
 {
  'branch': 'abc',
  'count(`branch`)' : n //a number
 },
 {
  'branch': 'xyz',
  'count(`branch`)' : x //a number
 },
]
```

if the structure is not similar to the one above, please post the json structure as well.

Answer code:

```
 String leadingText = 'No Data Found';
 String trailingText = '';
 try {
  leadingText = '${snapshot.data[index]["branch"]}';
  trailingText = '${snapshot.data[index]["count(`branch`)".toString()]}';
 } catch (e, s) {
  print('Exception while fetching data: $e stacktrace: $s );
 }
```

Use the Strings as normal string data in `Text`:

```
leading: new Text(
 leadingText,
 style: TextStyle(
  color: Colors.white,
  fontSize: 25.0,
 ),
),
trailing: new Text(
 trailingText,
 style: TextStyle(
  color: Colors.white,
  fontSize: 25.0,
 ),
),
```

This will allow you to handle the `format exception` and return your custom string as the response. However, you'll get the same string in case of any exception, so I'll suggest you Handle it in your own way.

Comment: Getting type string is not subtype of type int error....getcount() async {
         try{
      var data = await http
     .post("http://10.0.2.2/Flutter/count.php", body: {
    
        body: {
    
      "date": count,
      });
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);
     print(jsonData);

   return jsonData;
    }
    catch (e, s) {
  print('Exception while fetching data: $e stacktrace: $s' );
  return "No Data Found";
 }

Comment: instead of "No Data Found!" use -1 as return

Comment: still not solved my problem..getting the error...Class 'int' has no instance getter 'length'. Tried calling: length

Comment: I have tried to help, but without actual code I can't.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help...I have shared my code..please guide me..

Comment: Finally i got it. I followed the error handling from https://resocoder.com/2019/12/11/proper-error-handling-in-flutter-dart-1-principles/.. Thanks for your guidance...